# Sending mail with PHP and debian

Tags: php, email, postfix-mta

I am using postfix to send messages with the PHP mail function. I got it to work... kinda.
The issue I am having is that it works very sporadic. If I send a mail to my GMAIL it send the from header as root@hostname. Where can I change this? I would like it to send from conference@mydomain.se.

When I do send a mail using "php sendmail.php" I receive this in the /var/log/mail.log:

```
Aug 13 13:00:01 CONSERV25 postfix/cleanup[23503]: 6CEA1141037: message-id=<20130813110001.6CEA1141037@CONSERV25>
Aug 13 13:00:01 CONSERV25 postfix/qmgr[3937]: 6CEA1141037: from=<>, size=2409, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 13 13:00:01 CONSERV25 postfix/bounce[23507]: 6B70C141036: sender non-delivery notification: 6CEA1141037
Aug 13 13:00:01 CONSERV25 postfix/qmgr[3937]: 6B70C141036: removed
Aug 13 13:00:02 CONSERV25 postfix/local[23505]: 6CEA1141037: to=<smmsp@example.se>, relay=local, delay=1, delays=0.01/0/0/1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
Aug 13 13:00:02 CONSERV25 postfix/qmgr[3937]: 6CEA1141037: removed
```

What I need as a start is a way to change the sender from root@hostname to conference@mydomain.se. I have changed it in php.ini under [mail] but no effect there.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: I noticed it is possible to send mail as long as they are not internal. I can't send a mail from test@foo.bar to test2@foo.bar but to test@gmail.com.
<br>

It is a simple mail($addr, $subj, $mess, $header)

Answer (score 0):

If setting `sendmail_from` in `php.ini` doesnt work, try setting  custom "From:" header in mail function itself. This will also be used to set envelope sender address.